# How to format output of Select Name, LastWriteTime of PowerShell script in email using Send-MailMessage?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a script that sends an email daily, outlining the Name and LastWriteTime of folders in our environment that do not meet a required date.

I'm using Send-MailMessage in order to do this, however, the format of the list is not visually appealing, when I use the below code:

```
$body+= $Output1 | select name, LastWriteTime | format-list
$body+= $Output2 | select name, LastWriteTime | format-list
$body+= $Output3 | select name, LastWriteTime | format-list
```

It outputs the results in the following manner:

```
TITLE:

Name          : XXXX.txt
LastWriteTime : 2/8/2020 4:00:16 AM

Name          : XXXX.txt
LastWriteTime : 12/20/2018 12:20:29 AM

TITLE:


Name          : XXXX.Zip
LastWriteTime : 8/8/2019 1:40:09 AM

Name          : XXXX.Zip
LastWriteTime : 11/26/2018 12:00:23 AM

Name          : XXXX.Zip
LastWriteTime : 1/9/2019 9:40:49 AM


TITLE:

Name          : XXXX.Zip
LastWriteTime : 11/26/2018 12:00:23 AM

Name          : XXXX.Zip
LastWriteTime : 1/9/2019 9:40:49 AM
```

Therefore, it's not visually appealing in the email as it takes up a lot of space by printing the Name and LastWriteTime on separate lines. I have tried removing the format-list, and instead adding format-table, but this causes the results to look completely unorganized in the email, as shown here:

```
TITLE:

Name          LastWriteTime         
----                -------------         
XXXXXXX_XXX_XXXXXX.txt   2/8/2020 4:00:16 AM   
XXXXXXX_XXX_XXXXXX.txt 12/20/2018 12:20:29 AM

TITLE:

Name           LastWriteTime         
----              -------------         
XXXXXXX_XXXX_XXX.txt  2/8/2020 4:00:16 AM   
XXXXXXX_XXXX_XXX.txt 12/20/2018 12:20:29 AM

TITLE:

Name        LastWriteTime         
----             -------------         
XXXXXXX_XX_190807.zip 8/8/2019 1:40:09 AM   
XXXXXXX_XX_181125.zip    11/26/2018 12:00:23 AM
XXXXXXX_XX_190108.zip 1/9/2019 9:40:49 AM
```

Is there a way to output the results so that they look visually appealing, as in the Name and LastWriteTime are side by side and align with their respective data, and look formatted?

Furthermore, is there a way to make some other parts of the email report displayed in bold and in a different font size and to change "name" and "LastWriteTime" so that they are displayed as another word in the email in order to enhance the look :)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please keep in mind that the primary goal of PowerShell is to output objects. Pretty printing can be done, but that should happen after all objects are created. The result of `Format-List` is not often stored in a variable. Have a look at `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Isn't export-csv used for excel, though? How would this fit in the context of an email report? Thanks!

Comment: There are many tools out there, including Excel, to format CSV files. Yes, you can do the formatting with PowerShell if you really want. I would encourage you to make a CSV file with the desired contents, then format that into a file to email.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I shall try this method!

Comment: If you want to format the CSV file report with bold fonts and color, you might use the PowerShell module https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get that in a table format with one line:

```
$emtxt = ""   #  OK, two lines.  Let's initialize the string variable first
Get-childItem "<insert directory path her>" | Foreach {$emtxt += ($_.Name,"`t", $_.LastWriteTime,  "`n")}
```